# Regex in @RequestMapping

Tags: regex, spring-mvc

I have got stuck with the following. Lets say I have an url like

```
http://localhost:8080/a/somename-anyothername-onemorename-aAttributeId.html
http://localhost:8080/a/anyothername-onemorename-aAttributeId.html
http://localhost:8080/a/anyothername-onemorename-anyothername-anyothername-aAttributeId.html
...
```

In general the url may have a number of parts. My goal is to set the **AttributeId** part of the url above as a variable in @RequestMapping as it shown below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/a")
public class ProductPageController extends AbstractPageController
{

@RequestMapping(value = "/{attributeId:(?:[-a])(?!.*(?:[-a])).*}.html", method =      RequestMethod.GET)
     public String requestHandler(@PathVariable("attributeId") final String attributeId,   final Model model) {
          //method body
     }
}    
}
```

My question is what I do wrong with my regex? Should I split the regex somehow to escape everything before the aAttributeId.html part as the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{unused:*.}{productCode:(?:[-a])(?!.*(?:[-a])).*}.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Thanks for ideas

**Update: Answer for the question**

The final mapping looks as the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**{attributeId:a(?:[^-]+)}.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
-a([^-]+)\.html
```

NB: I don't know spring syntax.

Comment: @CyrilDeba: There was a typo, is it ok now?

Comment: I accepted your answer but it was slightly modified by me (see the updated question). Thanks a lot!